# Differences of heads and tails in a fair coin

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm very new to this so I would appreciate a detailed explanation.

I wrote a very simple Matlab program that "flips a coin" (`randi([1 2])`) $n$ times. Every time I get a new random number I see the difference between the number of heads and tails. I run the program with various $n$ values and I get:

```
Number of trials: 1,000,000.
Max difference: 1171.

Number of trials: 10,000,000.
Max difference: 6709.

Number of trials: 100,000,000.
Max difference: 18753.
```

How can I explain those numbers? Are they linked with some properties like the Variance(?) of which distribution?

**EDIT:** Is there any formula that can give me a bound to those differences?

Comment: What do you mean by **max.** difference ? Is it just the difference in 1,000,000 coin flips ?

Comment: Every time I toss a coin I mark the difference between the number of head and tails. Until we rich the end $n$ we have many different numbers of differences. I just keep the maximum occurrence and print it.

Comment: So you toss the coins 1 mio times but several times ? Or you toss for instance the coin 100,000 times and repeat this experiment 9 times ? In general you can conduct a hypothesis testing to evaluate if the coin is fair.

Comment: @callculus I toss it once, I mark the difference, I toss it twice, I mark the difference ... repeat $n$ times. I find and print the max number of marked. Then I wonder what is a reasonable (most like to happen) number I could have marked?

Comment: You are looking at $$M_n=\max\limits_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}|S_k|,$$ where $(S_k)$ is a standard random walk starting from $S_0=0$ which makes $\pm1$ steps with equal probabilities. Donsker's theorem shows that $$\frac{M_n}{\sqrt{n}}\to Z=\max\limits_{0\leqslant t\leqslant1}|B_t|,$$ in distribution, where $(B_t)$ is a standard Brownian motion, and one knows that the distribution of $Z$ is such that, for every positive $z$, $$P(Z<z)=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\exp\left(-\frac{(2k+1)^2\pi^2t}{8z^2}\right).$$ Thus, $Z$ is *not* gaussian...

Answer (score 1):

First, randi([1 2]) will give you a uniform distribution from 1 to 2. And you said that you will count the difference between number of heads and number of tails.

In general, if the coin-flip experiment is fair, the probability of getting a head should be the same as the probability of getting a tail = 0.5. That means the difference should be zero.

But in reality, especially when the number of coin-flip is small, it is possible to get more heads than tails, or vice versa.

But from your code, you can calculate such "wrong occurrence" as a percentage as $\frac{\text{number of difference}}{\text{number of total coin flip}}$. And as you can see, as n gets bigger, this percentage gets smaller which means that the differences of heads and tails become smaller, opposed to number of the total coin flip.

Comment: Is there any formula that can give me a bound to those differences?

Comment: The upper bound is the number of trials - it is possible (although extremely, extremely rare) for there to be all heads and no tails. The lower bound is the negative of this. The expected difference is 0. The distribution of differences in the experiment will be binomial, which converges to a a normal distribution as your trials tends to infinity. The mean of the distribution will be 0 and the variance will be n/4.

Comment: @Oracular Thanks! So does this n/4 mean that I should expect the number of my heads or tails to be around(/up to?) 1,000,000/4 = 250,000? Because I get results at the order of magnitude of 1000s.

Comment: The variance is the standard deviation squared (so the standard deviation is sqrt(n)/2). With the normal distribution, 68% of observations will occur within one standard deviation, 95% will occur within two, and 99.7% will occur within three. In other words, if you run this experiment with 1,000,000 coins a very large number of times, 68% of the time you will find that the number of differences is <sqrt(1,000,000)/2=500. 95% of the time, you will find that the difference is <2sqrt(1,000,000)/2=1000. 99.7% of the time, you will find that the difference is <3sqrt(1,000,000)/2=1500.

Comment: @Oracular Thanks that was clear!